# How to keep divs side by side in bootstrap 2.2.2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KKQsK/3/)
at first the form fields are coming and after that image is coming.But I want as per the image attached.
I have made a separate div class of span6 inside

```
<div id="patient" class="tab-pane "
```

but still the style is not coming as per the screenshot.

Can any body tell me how to get?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span1"></div>
                <div class="span10"
                    style="margin-bottom: 6px; margin-top: 0px; background: #efeee9">
                <img
                        src="/MoDoc/resources/ui_resources/img/mo doc title.jpg"
                        alt="" align="left">
                    <h2 align="center" style="margin-top: 18px;"></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="span1"></div>
            </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="projectUrl" value="/MoDoc/">
<div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span1"></div>
                <div class="span10"
                    style="background: #eee; border: 1px solid #ddd;">
    <div id="patient" class="tab-pane "
                                style="margin-left: 28px; margin-right: 48px;">
    <p>
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Name :</label>
        <input class="span8" type="text" data-bind="value: name"
         data-required="true" data-trigger="change" name="name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Department :</label>
    <select class="span8" name="department" 
                    data-bind="options: departmentOptions,value: department,optionsCaption: 'Select Department'"
                    data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
                </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Gender :</label>
                <select class="span8" name="gender" 
                    data-bind="options: genderOptions,value: gender,optionsCaption: 'Select Gender'"
                    data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
                </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Degree :</label>
        <select class="span8" name="degree" 
                    data-bind="options: degreeOptions,value: degree,optionsCaption: 'Select Degree'"
                    data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
                </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Username :</label>
        <input class="span8" type="text" 
            data-bind="value: username"
            name="username" data-required="true"
            data-trigger="change" 
            data-remote="/MoDoc/isUserNameExists" 
            data-remote-method="GET">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Password :</label>                 
            <input class="span8" type="password"
             data-bind="value: password"
             name="password"
             data-required="true"
             data-trigger="change">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Mobile :</label>
        <input class="span8"  type="text" data-bind="value: mobile"
             data-type="number"
             data-minlength="10"
             data-required="true" 
             data-trigger="change" data-type="phone" name="mobile">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Email address :</label>
        <input class="span8" type="text"
             data-bind="value: email" data-required="true" 
             data-trigger="change" data-type="email" name="email">
    </p>
    <div class="span6">
<!--<div data-bind="template: {name: 'profileImageTemplate'}"></div>    -->
<div style="margin-top: 28px;">         
<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
    <div data-bind="if: imgSrc">
        <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;"><img data-bind="attr: { src: imgSrc }"/></div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="ifnot: imgSrc">
    <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;"><img src="ui_resources/img/profile_pic.png" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 150px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
    <div>
    <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" data-bind=" file: imgFile, fileObjectURL: imgSrc"/></span>
    <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>



</div>
 </div>
    <div align="center">
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary"
                                                    >
                                                    <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Save
                                                </button>
                                                <button class="btn"
                                                    >
                                                    <i class="icon-remove"></i> Cancel
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- container -->
```

[image]

Comment: the fiddle aint working

Comment: @Richa sorry,i Have corrected now

Comment: @Janak Please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap all your inputs to div and give `span6` class to that div.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KKQsK/4/)

Comment: Thanks for answering,+1.I will just look at your answer

Comment: Bootstrap width totals span12; so, as your other fields are span 8 you must make image span4 or as Morpheus suggests make form span6 too. E.G span6 and span6 or span8 and span4 will work. At minute they total 8 + 6 = 14 so they go to next line.

Comment: Thanks @DanniB for extended explanation :)

Comment: @DaniB Thanks to you also for giving more info